# Blender 2.x and 3.x start takes several minutes

Tags: customization, performance

I´m using blender on different machines.
On my private device it´s running and starting without problems.

On my company device it´s starting super slow and takes up to 2min to start.
Once blender is running, it takes again several minutes if i go to preferences, try to save, import or to change the renderer, so everything blender system related.

Device:
Dell Precision 5500, i7--10875H, nvidia quadro t2000
OS: win7

Suggestion:
Blender or Windows is trying to connect to some network drives. Even if disconnect all network drives, it does the same. Also blender reset was not changing anything.

It´s right now no fun to work with blender on this device.

Comment: I don't know if this is your problem or not, but in recent revisions, add-on makers have been adding code to their add-ons to "call home" to find out if there's a newer version of the add-on.  Depending on what add-ons I have enabled it can take up to 90 seconds on my system.  Maybe try disabling all add-ons and seeing if startup time improves?

Comment: do you have a customized startup file on the company device? If so, you could try starting Blender there using the `--factory-startup` command line switch

Comment: thanks for quick reply. I´ve no add-on installted. It´s a clean install with blender 3.1, also tried 3.2 alpha. all same. Takes long time to start and to make changes like "file/open" dialog call takes up to 1min to appear.

Comment: Using  --factory-startup command line switch  was not changing startup behaviour

Comment: Every dialog i´m open is resulting in a "not responding" from blender.

Comment: Tried out blender 2.79.2 and this is loading quick and have no lagging at all while clicking on system dialogs. really strange.

Comment: Ok.. it seems to be an issue with OpenGL. I updated all drivers of integrated (intel UHD) and dedicated graphics card (t2000 quadro). Also tried the opengl32.dll method to run blender. This was making blender to start faster, but was resulting in less performance / fps in viewport. So i switched back to default method and ended up in slow startup and slow system dialogs again. starting blender with command line was not showing an issues. It´s some driver issue probably.